# K8s can't access kube-ui on gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I follow this docs `https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook` to created a Guestbook on GCE. And everything works fine.

But when I try to access kube-ui. I am totally confused.

first

```
≥ kubectl get svc                                                                                                                        14:29
NAME           LABELS                                    SELECTOR            IP(S)            PORT(S)
frontend       name=frontend                             name=frontend       10.191.254.236   80/TCP
                                                                             146.148.x.x    
kubernetes     component=apiserver,provider=kubernetes   <none>              10.191.240.1     443/TCP
redis-master   name=redis-master                         name=redis-master   10.191.253.125   6379/TCP
redis-slave    name=redis-slave                          name=redis-slave    10.191.254.248   6379/TCP
```

I can access my guestbook by 146.148.x.x;
But I can't access web-ui through this ip.
So I think this is not the master IP of my GCE. Then I execute this:

```
≥ kubectl get endpoints                                                                                                                  14:33
NAME           ENDPOINTS
frontend       10.188.0.6:80,10.188.0.7:80,10.188.2.4:80 + 2 more...
kubernetes     104.197.x.x:443
redis-master   10.188.2.7:6379
redis-slave    10.188.0.8:6379,10.188.2.3:6379
```

Now, I got another IP, and I try to access kube-ui through this IP.
I can get response from the server. But It will need Authtication.

How can I get access to the kube-ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I got it

```
gcloud container clusters describe CLUSTER-NAME
```

contains username and password!

Answer (score 0):

The 146.148.x.x IP listed under "frontend" service is there because of this entry in the service spec:

> "type": "LoadBalancer"

It allows your application to be access externally.

Another useful command is

> kubectl cluster-info

Answer (score 0):

Also it can be checked out for detailed kubelctl config in following 2 ways:

- client config file -   *~/.kube/config*
- Develop Console - [GCP project]/[GCE instance], show in table of *Custom meta data*, *kube-env* row